# Why is jQuery not detecting dynamically loaded jQuery Mobile buttons?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I loaded the following HTML via Ajax into a web page powered by jQuery Mobile. What's important is the class name of `onButton` attached to the anchor tag.

```
<a class="onButton ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-up-c" href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="c"><span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all"><span class="ui-btn-text">Turn On</span></span></a>
```

After loading via Ajax, I triggered a "create event" to apply jQuery Mobile button styles per the documentation.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/loadAllButtons',
    context: $('contentBox'),
    cache: false,
    data: {'listOfEntities': JSON.stringify([1,2,3,4,5])},
    success: function(data) {
        $(this).html(data).trigger( "create" );
    }
});
```

I see that the buttons have been successfully loaded. However, when I call `console.log($('.onButton').length);`, the console displays 0.

That is interesting because Chrome Web Developer notes 5 instances of `<a>` tags with the `onButton` class loaded via Ajax.

Why is jQuery not detecting the newly loaded anchor tags (or buttons)?

---

To be clear, here is how I am debugging:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/loadAllButtons',
    context: $('contentBox'),
    cache: false,
    data: {'listOfEntities': JSON.stringify([1,2,3,4,5])},
    success: function(data) {
        $(this).html(data).trigger( "create" );
    }
});
console.log($('.onButton').length);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your debugging `console.log()` in the callback for the AJAX call. As it is, the `console.log()` is running just after the request is sent (since by default AJAX requests are asynchronous), which will be before the response is received from the server and therefore before any elements have been added to the DOM.

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/loadAllButtons',
    context: $('contentBox'),
    cache: false,
    data: {'listOfEntities': JSON.stringify([1,2,3,4,5])},
    success: function(data) {
        $(this).html(data).trigger( "create" );
        console.log($('.onButton').length);
    }
});
```

Also, since you are adding button elements to the DOM that already have the jQuery Mobile classes/structure applied, you may need to call `.button('refresh')` to refresh the elements instead of `.trigger('create')` to initialize them. I haven't used `.button('refresh')` before so I'm not sure if you can call it on an ancestor element of the buttons or if you have to call it on the buttons themselves like:

```
$(this).html(data).find('.onButton').button( "refresh" );
```

Comment: Thank you, calling `console.log($('.onButton').length);` within the success callback function worked. Interestingly though, it worked with a create event, but not a refresh event. I think it's because I need to initialize the elements loaded.